# In continuation of my attempts to understand std::enable_if usage

Tags: c++14, sfinae

In this piece of code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <type_traits>
#include <ios>

using std::enable_if;
using std::is_same;
using std::boolalpha;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename T>
struct S {
  S(): t(static_cast<T>(NULL)) { }

  // void type() {
  //   cout << boolalpha;
  //   cout << is_same<T,int>::value << endl;
  // }

  template <typename enable_if<is_same<T,int>::value,T>::type>
  void type() {
    cout << boolalpha << true << endl;
  }

  T t;
};

int main(){
  S<int> s;
  s.type();
  return(0);
}
```

I get successful compilation and output for the method `type()` implemented as a non-template function; however, for the same method implemented as a template function using `std::enable_if` I get the following compilation error:

```
so_main.cpp:23:11: error: no matching member function for call to 'type'
        s.type();
        ~~^~~~
so_main.cpp:15:73: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument ''
        template<typename enable_if<is_same<T,int>::value,T>::type>void type(){cout << boolalpha << true << endl;}
                                                                        ^
1 error generated.
```

My understanding is that the logic implemented in both cases is similar.
When the method is non-template, the type for `T` is corroborated as `int`. However, when `std::enable_if` is used to enable the template function for the same condition (i.e., `T` is `int`), the code does not compile.

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? Because of the rent at the beginning? Otherwise, it's a perfectly valid and well-phrased question; and a lot of people have problem with this peculiarity of SFINAE.

Comment: @@SU3 it is unfortunate and deplorable that there is a lot of arbitrariness going around in the conduct of certain members of this forum, as evinced by the down voting of this post, with no explanation whatsoever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because SFINAE only works on template parameters pertaining to the template itself. The standard calls that *immediate context*. In your code example, `T` is a template parameter of the class template, not of the member function template.

You can circumvent this by giving your function a dummy template parameter that defaults to `T`, and using SFINAE on it instead, like this:

```cpp
template <typename U=T>
typename enable_if<is_same<U,int>::value>::type type() {
  cout << boolalpha << true << endl;
}
```